# summarizing array of void * values

Tags: c, macros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 5

#define sum_mac(func,type)\
    void* func (void* arr, int size)\
    {\
    int i;\
    type *sum = (type*)malloc(sizeof(type));\
    if(sum == NULL)\
    {\
        printf("Error\n");\
        exit(1);\
    }\
    *sum = 0;\
    for(i = 0; i<size ; i++)\
    {\
        *sum = *sum + *((type*)arr[i]);\
    }\
    return sum;\
    }\
sum_mac(int_sum,int);
void *summary(void* arr, int size, void *(*func)(void*, int))
{
    if (func == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return (*func)(arr, size);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int *sum = summary(arr, LEN, int_sum(arr, LEN));
    printf("the sum is: %d ", *sum);
    free(sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when I try to compile this code:

> Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _int_sum referenced in function _main

When I searched possible causes for this problem I got that *"a reference to a function or variable that the linker can't resolve, or find a definition for"*.

Can someone help me find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is (at least) three problems:

You included the macro instanciation in the macro itself, change:

```
}\
sum_mac(int_sum,int);
```

to:

```
}
sum_mac(int_sum,int);
```

Thus `sum_mac` is not part of the macro.

In the macro definition, change:

```
*sum = *sum + *((type*)arr[i]);
```

to:

```
*sum = *sum + ((type*)arr)[i];
```

In the first case, you try to use indexing on void pointer type, which is not possible (void has no size). So convert `arr` to pointer of the right type and use arithmetic on it.

--------------EDIT-----------

Change:

```
int *sum = summary(arr, LEN, int_sum(arr, LEN));
```

to

```
int *sum = summary(arr, LEN, int_sum);
```

In the first case you call `summary` with the third parameter value being the result of a call to `int_sum`, and that result if not a function pointer but the pointer to some `int`. You need to pass the function pointer.

Most of your problems are due to macro usage. This bypass the type system and fool the compiler, which is never a good idea.

Comment: This compiles, but it crashes.

Comment: Yes I didn't corrected the *logic*. This is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
    return sum;\
    }\ <---------- Remove the \
sum_mac(int_sum,int);  <---- also remove the ; because this is not a statement
void *summary(void* arr, int size, void *(*func)(void*, int))
```

Compiler thinks that `sum_mac(int_sum,int);` is part of the macro definition because `\` at the end of line concatenates lines. That is why `sum_mac(int_sum,int);` is never called.

However, this reveals another problem with operator precendence on line:

```
*sum = *sum + *((type*)arr[i]);\
```

Array access `[i]` has higher precedence than cast `(type*)`, so you are trying to access `void` array which won't work. Also the last dereference is pointless. Line should be changed to:

```
*sum = *sum + ((type*)arr)[i];\
```

There is also third problem: You are passing calling `int_sum` too early. Function expects function pointer so you should only pass the pointer:

```
int *sum = summary(arr, LEN, int_sum); // Only pass int_sum
```

You should make sure that you have enabled all warnings on the compiler, since this is an error that compiler could warn you about.

Comment: @MichaelWalz because there is another problem in the macro itself... The answer does correct the initial problem (provided the macro will be corrected).

Answer (score 0):

The other problem is here:

```
int *sum = summary(arr, LEN, int_sum(arr, LEN));
```

The third argument of `summary` should be a *function pointer*, but `int_sum(arr, LEN)` is not a function pointer but it is the result of the `int_sum` function.

You need to write this:

```
int *sum = summary(arr, LEN, int_sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare the function you call anywhere, so the linker doesn't know what to do.

That being said, putting whole functions inside macros is not a good idea, nor to malloc single items. And the code `*sum = *sum + *((type*)arr[i]);` goes wildly out of bounds, because you didn't allocate an array, but use it as if it was one.

I would rewrite this from scratch. This is what you can do instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int int_sum (size_t size, int arr[size])
{
  int sum = 0;
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

float float_sum (size_t size, float arr[size])
{
  float sum = 0.0f;
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

#define sum_array(arr) _Generic((arr[0]), \
                         int:   int_sum,  \
                         float: float_sum) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), arr)

int main (void)
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int sum = sum_array(arr);
    printf("int, the sum is: %d\n", sum);

    float farr[] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}; 
    printf("float, the sum is: %f\n", sum_array(farr));

    return 0;
}
```

Which can be made even more generic, even without involving function pointers:

```
#define do_stuff(arr, stuff) _Generic((arr[0]), \
                         int:   int_##sum,  \
                         float: float_##sum) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), arr)

int main (void)
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int sum = do_stuff(arr, sum);
    printf("int, the sum is: %d\n", sum);

    float farr[] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}; 
    printf("float, the sum is: %f\n", do_stuff(farr, sum));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how your implementation would be different if i was asked to sum the array values in a function not a macro?

Comment: @safaatareef This uses functions, the macro is only there to pick the right one based on the type used.